# Encrypt a string in power virtual agent and power automate

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, power-automate, power-virtual-agents

I have created a bot using power virtual agent which will assist user in changing their password. User need to pass their current and new password for this. And then I am calling power automate flow and then making use of API `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/changePassword` to change password by passing body as

```
{
    "currentPassword": "Test123456",
    "newPassword": "Test12345678"
}
```

I see a security issue here wherein execution history gets stored in power automate and admin can see users passwords using it.
Any idea on how to overcome this?

Comment: Hi , Thanks for reaching out ,You can overcome this by deleting the history every time , hope this helps .

Answer (score 0):

You can enable secure input and secure output in the settings an Power Automate actions.

[image]

After enabling it will show up like below in the flow history.

[image]